# Why does an ASN path link to itself?

Tags: networking, dns

in the list of paths here: http://archive.routeviews.org/dnszones/

I stumbled across this portion of an entry

$183.144.2      IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.183.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
184.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.184.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
185.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.185.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
186.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.186.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
187.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.187.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
188.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.188.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
189.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.189.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
190.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.190.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
191.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
*.191.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"
192.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 20485 12389 12880 44244" "2.144.192.0" "20"
*.192.144.2     IN TXT  "8492 20485 12389 12880 44244" "2.144.192.0" "20"
193.144.2       IN TXT  "8492 20485 12389 12880 44244" "2.144.192.0" "20"$

If you see:

$*.191.144.2        IN TXT  "8492 34224 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 34984 48159 48159 48159 48159" "2.144.176.0" "20"$ for example.

34984 links to itself 9 times before linking to 48159. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "links to itself 9 times" you appear to mean "appears 9 times is a row in the AS path". AS paths aren't a linked link or anything so I'm not sure why you're using the terminology "links".

Prepending your AS to an AS path multiple times is a commonly used technique to deprefer a route. Because one of the criteria in the BGP route selection algorithm is AS path length, a route whose path has more ASes in it is less likely to be used than one with fewer.

Note that prepending after prepending 3 or 4 times, additional prepending is unlikely to be useful on most of the Internet. A typical router is unlikely to see two routes of otherwise equal preference for the same destination that differ in AS path length by more than 3 or 4. Plus, most routers will prefer a certain set of routes (e.g. customer routes) over another set (e.g. transit routes) using a parameter (local-preference) that is more important than AS path length, so in that case prepending even once to try to influence those routers' path selection is futile.